RYU Controller: How to Force OpenFlow Switch to Send PacketIn Events Even When a Flow Exists in Switch?
I'm using the RYU controller and OpenFlow switches to secure my network by monitoring traffic. However, I’m facing an issue where I don’t receive PacketIn events from the switch after a flow has been created. My current understanding is:
When a flow exists: The OpenFlow switch forwards packets based on the flow rule, but it does not send a PacketIn event to the controller.
When no flow exists: The switch buffers the packet and waits for a command from the controller to either forward or drop it, generating a PacketIn event.

I want to monitor traffic continuously, even for existing flows, to detect unusual activity. Specifically, I’d like to configure the OpenFlow switch so that:
Packets are not buffered when there is an active flow but are forwarded directly.
A PacketIn event is sent to the controller with each forwarded packet, allowing me to inspect the traffic for security monitoring.

I know I can simply remove flow rules and not add any flow to switch but it is necessary to have both in my case.
Is there a way to achieve this behavior in RYU/OpenFlow? I'd appreciate any advice or sample code that could help implement this functionality.
